# How many ways can the people sit in the bus?

Tags: combinatorics

There are $8$ people and they want to sit in a bus which has $2$ single front seats and $4$ sets of $3$ seats with $1$ person that is always the designated driver. How many ways are there for the people to sit in the bus?

I solved it by using:

$6!*(\binom{9}{3}) - 4((6*5*4*3)*2(\binom{4}{2})+(6*5*4*3*2)(\binom{3}{2}) + 6!(\binom{2}{2})) + 7!*(\binom{10}{3})-4((7*6*5*4)*3!*(\binom{5}{2})+(7*6*5*4*3)*2!*(\binom{4}{2})+(7*6*5*4*3*2)(\binom{3}{2}) + 7!(\binom{2}{2}) = \boxed{233280}$

I did complementary counting and took out the cases where there were more than $3$ people in a set of rows. Can anyone tell me if my answer is right?

Comment: What do you consider to be different ways to sit? Are permutations of three people in the same set different?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: I don't understand the problem,  are there $9$ people, with Alicia always driving? Then Alicia doesn't matter.

Comment: Then it is irrelevant the configuration of seats, it only matters the number of seats, 14+1 driver, right?

Comment: Oh, I assumed one of the 8 (any one of the 8) would be the driver.  But the arrangements of the seats seems utterly irrelevant to me.  Isn't 14 plus the driver?

Answer (score 3):

If the specific seat matters, it seems like there should be an $8$ way choice to choose the driver, then in the remaining $14$ seats, we have to choose $7$ for the remaining passengers, which gives $8{14 \choose 7}$.

Comment: Since order matters it'd be 8*(14!/7!) but as the driver is a ninth irrelevant person it is 14!/6!.  But you are a lot closer then the weird mess the OP did which make his/her criticism seem a little ... unjustifiably strident if you ask me.

Comment: Oh, I had assumed it was one of the 8 people to drive rather than a 9th, my bad.

Comment: I was using distributions to solve it but I am unsure where the fault is.

Answer (score 2):

If it's the same person driving then the answer is $14!/6!$ or 14*13*... 7.  There are 14 choices for the first person, 13 for the second, and so on.

The arrangements of the seats and the driver are utterly irrelevant.

====

Why isn't it just $8*14!/7!$?  One of the eight people has to drive and the remaining 7 have to sit in the fourteen seats.

You can't move the seats around so specifying that there are 2 front seats and 4 sets or 3 is of no importance any more than indicating what color they are or whether they have gum stuck under them.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is correct. But it should be $7!*\binom{14}{7}$ since we already chose one person to drive.

Comment: But you said it was a 9th person driving.

Comment: No, I said there are $8$ people and $1$ of them always drives.

Comment: Also, order matters right so we should multiply it by $7!$?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at another, viable(?) interpretation:

Take the one driver and put him/her in the driver's seat (one of the two single front seats).  That leaves seven **distinguishable** people and $13$ **distinguishable seats**.

Add six **identical** empty boxes to the seven passengers.  Arrange these $13$ items in $13!$ ways.  Then divide by $6!$ to eliminate double counting from switching around the empty boxes..

These $13$ items file onto the bus in some constant, defined way.  The empty boxes take up empty seats.